# Converting html to svg using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

Is there a way to convert an html snippet to svg?

for example:
`<b>This is bolded</b>`

I want to make an svg document with the html snippet above... is this possible?

Comment: Not a definitive reference, but enough to get you going: http://www.w3schools.com/svg/default.asp

Comment: And here is a quick tutorial on using the text element: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/text-element.html

Comment: @RobG but does it actually take HTML code and converts it to svg? What I am trying to do is to create an svg by supplying the innerHTML of a div element without doing any manual changes.

Comment: To use in-line svg in those browsers that support it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/svg_in_html_introduction

Comment: [MDN: Drawing DOM objects into a canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas)

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest that you should edit your question to describe the actual use case and goal you are trying to achieve, as directly implementing what you seem to ask for is hard (see below). Some combination of [SVG-in-XHTML](http://phrogz.net/SVG/svg_in_xhtml5.xhtml) or [XHTML-in-SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG/Tutorial/Other_content_in_SVG#Embedding_arbitrary_XML) (for example, [this](http://ajaxian.com/archives/foreignobject-hey-youve-got-html-in-my-svg)) are far more likely to give you want you want.

We can only help you achieve your goals if you tell us your goals instead of asking us help you to solve a particular implementation you thought of to achieve them.

---

As I mentioned above, There is not an easy way to do what you suggest. In particular, HTML has automatic line wrapping, floating and general positioning concepts, as well as explicit z-indexing, that are not present in SVG.

The following madness would mostly work, however:

- Create an iframe or div on your page and set the HTML to your snippet.
- Loop through every element and convert wrap a `margin:0;padding:0;border:0` span around every word in the text.
- Loop through every element (including your created spans) and calculate the absolute position on the page. (jQuery has a method to do this, or you could use the combination of `offsetLeft`/`offsetTop` and `offsetParent` to walk up the positioned tree and calculate it yourself.)

  - Calculate the equivalent z-index for each element by walking up the tree and using the `getComputedStyle()` and creating a chain of the local z-index.
  - For each of these elements, create the equivalent element in SVG with absolute positioning.
- Re-sort the SVG elements you created by the hierarchy of z-indices.

Comment: problem with svg foreignObject tag is that it is not supported by ie 9 and also you cannot serialize the SVG

Comment: Does someone implemented that "madness"? I need to load SVGs in a <img> tag and `foreignObject` [don't works well](https://codepen.io/qgustavor/pen/bLarww) in this case.

Answer (score 5):

Check this [html to SVG demo](http://www.hiqpdf.com/demo/ConvertHtmlToSvg.aspx), (using HiQPDF, a commercial product). You can find there code samples for C# and VB.NET. You can convert an URL or a HTML code snippet as you requested.

Comment: Great software. What a pity that they don't have a reasonably prized product but only the library targeted at developers.

Answer (score 3):

There are JS libs, that convert html to canvas:
http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/
But until now, I did not found something similar for svg.

Comment: I had some luck combining `html2canvas` with [canvas2svg](https://github.com/gliffy/canvas2svg): you can pass in a `canvas` element to `html2canvas` via the options; if you wrap an `canvas2svg` as a dummy HTML `canvas` element and pass it into `html2canvas`, it "draws" into an SVG instead of a `canvas`. But `canvas2svg` is not perfect yet, so you should verify that the results are good enough for your purposes

Comment: e.g. something like: `var fauxCanvas = {
  ctx: new C2S(),
  getContext: function(){
    return this.ctx;
  },
  style: {},
  ownerDocument: document
};
html2canvas(domNode, {canvas: fauxCanvas}).then(...`