# Accessing Sinatra scope from another class

Tags: ruby, scope, sinatra

I'm running a Sinatra application with a few extra classes pulled in for creating a User and a few others on the fly (no DB, it feeds in from a web service). I'm trying send out a flash notice (using https://github.com/nakajima/rack-flash) from within my User model but can't figure out how to get access to the flash method/variable because I'm out of scope.

Something like:

```
class User
  def something
    if true
      flash[:notice] = 'Good job'
    else
      # nope
    end
  end
end
```

Which gets required into the Sinatra app by a simple `require 'models/user'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an XY Problem[1]. Sinatra is responsible for sending out flash messages, not your User objects, so the code for setting the flash should be in your Sinatra app, not in your User class.

[1] http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341

Answer (score 1):

You should not ask your User (model) to talk to the UI (view). That's bad/not MVC-clean. That's what a controller is for.

You can use either return values, exceptions, or `throw/catch` (which is not exception handling) to pass information from your model to your controller. For example, using return values:

```
post "/create_user" do
  flash[:notice] = case User.something
    when User   then "User Created!"
    when :nono  then "That's not allowed"
    when :later then "User queued to be created later."
  end
end

class User
  def self.something
    if authorized
      if can_create_now
        new(...)
      else
        queue_create(...)
        :later
      end
    else
      :nono
    end
  end
end
```

---

Since I mentioned them above, following are examples using **throw/catch** and **begin/rescue** (exceptions). As the advisability of using either of these constructs is questionable, let us take a moment of silence to ponder if this is a good idea.

---

Here is an example using **throw/catch**:

```
post "/create_user" do
  result = catch(:msg){ User.something }
  flash[:notice] = case 
    when :nono  then "That's not allowed"
    when :later then "User queued to be created later."
    else             "User Created!"
  end
end

class User
  def self.something
    throw :msg, :nono unless authorized
    if can_create_now
      new(...)
    else
      queue_create(...)
      throw :msg, :later
    end
  end
end
```

Finally, here's an example using **exceptions**, though I'm not convinced that this will be appropriate for all (non-disastrous) cases where you want to flash unique messages to the user:

```
post "/create_user" do
  flash[:notice] = "User Created!" # Assume all good
  begin
    User.something
  rescue User::Trouble=>e
    flash[:notice] = case e
      when Unauthorized  then "That's not allowed"
      when DelayedCreate then "User queued to be created later."
      else                    "Uh...Something bad happened."
    end
  end
end

class User
  class Trouble < RuntimeError; end
  class Unauthorized  < Trouble; end
  class DelayedCreate < Trouble; end
  def self.something
    raise Unauthorized unless authorized
    if can_create_now
      new(...)
    else
      queue_create(...)
      raise DelayedCreate
    end
  end
end
```

Exceptions let you pass an additional data along (e.g. `raise Unauthorized.new "No such account"`, or any custom properties you want to add to your class), and so may be more useful (when appropriate). Just remember to pass *semantic* results from your model to your controller, and let it translate them into *user-facing* messages.

Comment: ffs don't use throw or exceptions. You're replacing a bad design decision with an even worse design decision.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs If a method that is supposed to create a user cannot create a user, I think that an Exception is wholly appropriate. Further, catching any Exception and translating it into a human-readable error message is also a good idea. As I stated above, I believe this is only appropriate when you would normally raise an exception. As for `throw/catch`...I have only used it once in 12 years of programming Ruby, so I can't really justify it as strongly. :)

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Perhaps you would like to amend your answer with a suggestion for how to actually implement your advice.

Comment: @Phrogz 1) Exceptions should be used for *exceptional* cases. As a guideline (from PragProg), if you can't remove your exception handling without the code breaking, you are using exceptions incorrectly. DelayedCreate seems to be a good example. 2) You can rescue multiple exception types similarly to a case statement, so using a case statement inside the rescue is unnecessary. 3) When someone asks a question that contains an XY problem, the best thing to do is inform them so they can restate their question, not to try to answer it as asked.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs 1) With due deference to the PragProg, by that logic Ruby should not have a `rescue` clause. 2) Yes, but using multiple rescue blocks makes the code less DRY, and using multiple exception types removes flexibility. 3) I appreciate your feedback, and in general [I do just that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534128/converting-html-to-svg-using-javascript-jquery/5542595#5542595). However, when the question is reasonable, I also try to answer it, in case the OP _does_ know what they are doing. As in the past on IRC, I think you and I will just have to agree to disagree. :)

Comment: I don't think throw/catch is the way to go but I think you're right that I was definitely breaking the whole MVC thing (which, BTW, Sinatra is not beholden too, so really whatever works is cool). I ended up creating some controller-style actions that act as a middleware kinda thing between the Sinatra routes and the actual data. I went this way instead of just using the Sinatra routes to keep everything dry on my side.