# Text invert based on background image

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it even possible to obtain something like this only with CSS/CSS3 or with javascript? but no image for text.

[image]

Comment: It *is* possible with pure CSS, but AFAIK you can do this only with WebKit browsers, using a mix of CSS masks and filters.

Comment: Whoa, I really don't get the downvotes.

Comment: Agreed. Why are people downvoting this? It's a reasonable question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With limited support from old browsers, you can achieve this with text clipping:

for this html:

```
<div class="filter">
<div class="base">SOME TEXT</div>
</div>
```

with that CSS:

```
.filter {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, black 0%,black 50%,white 51%,white 100%);
}
.base {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 80px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, white 0%,white 50%,black 51%,black 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
}
```

You will get the background from the base (that has the inverted colors of the first div) to show only thru the text.

[webkit demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AEbmK/)

**Editing**

Have found that it can be done in a single element. The style would be:

```
.base {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 80px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, white 0%,white 50%,black 51%,black 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, black 0%,black 50%,white 51%,white 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text, border;
    color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: i'll mark this answer as the right one. Thank you! Hopefully mozilla, opera and ie10 will support in the future the text property of the background-clip.

Comment: Glad it helped. Hopefully opera will suport that soon since they are changing to webkit.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this in CSS you would need to use gradients. One for the background and one for the text, the gradient would be constant . see this for generating them: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ to produce this:

```
    background: #000000; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #000000 0%, #000000 50%, #ffffff 51%, #ffffff 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#000000), color-stop(50%,#000000), color-stop(51%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#ffffff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #000000 0%,#000000 50%,#ffffff 51%,#ffffff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #000000 0%,#000000 50%,#ffffff 51%,#ffffff 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #000000 0%,#000000 50%,#ffffff 51%,#ffffff 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(135deg,  #000000 0%,#000000 50%,#ffffff 51%,#ffffff 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
```

the main problem you still face though is not being able to "detect" the background image in order to make the text color opposite.

**If you wanted to detect the background you could look into the webkit -webkit-background-composite which has an XOR and plus-darker and plus-lighter for composite effects**

Hope this helps.

Comment: i know how to use gradients for div's spans or other block elemnts, but how do i use it for text? I'll gie the -webkit-background-composite tag a try

Comment: I would convert your text to svg in order to be able to use css background on it. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742148/how-to-convert-text-to-svg-paths

Comment: changing the text to svg wouldn't solve my problem, i need the text to be changeable via CMS and readable by search engines. I also tried the webkit composite but it didn't work either, the text would need to be also an image.

Comment: So transform to SVG using javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534128/converting-html-to-svg-using-javascript-jquery